# Deduplication in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

Situation:-
Table 'A' is receiving data from OracleGoldenGate feed and gets the data as New,Updated,Duplicate feed that either creates a new record or rewrites the old one based on it's characteristics (N/U/D). Every entry in table has its UpdatedTimeStamp column contain insertion timestamp.

Scope:-
To write a StoredProcedure in Oracle that pulls the data for a time period based on UpdatedTimeStamp column and publishes an xml using DBMSXMLGEN. 
How can I ensure that a duplicate entered in the table is not processed again ??

FYI-am currently filtering via a new table that I created, named as 'A-stg' and has old data inserted incrementally.

Comment: Could you please provide us with the necessary table names and column names to provide you the necessary query

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood the question, there are a few ways to avoid duplicates.

The most obvious is to use `DISTINCT`, e.g.

```
select distinct data_column from your_table
```

Another one is to use timestamp column and get only the last (or the first?) value, e.g.

```
select data_column, max(timestamp_column) 
from your_table
group by data_column
```